# Bash LANGUAGE variable logic

Tags: bash, internationalization

Can someone explain the logic of the LANGUAGE environment variable to me. I just don't get why the 2nd and especially the 3rd examples here are in french. Shouldn't they all be in english ?

```
$ LANGUAGE=en_US gerp
No command 'gerp' found, did you mean: Command 'grep' from package 'grep' (main)
$ LANGUAGE=en_US:fr gerp
La commande « gerp » est introuvable, vouliez-vous dire : La commande « grep » du paquet « grep » (main)
$ LANGUAGE=en_US:fr:it gerp
La commande « gerp » est introuvable, vouliez-vous dire : La commande « grep » du paquet « grep » (main)
```

Answer (score 2):

I did some tests and it seems like it goes through the list and stops at the first language that is known. That, and `en_US` doesn't seem to be a valid `LANGUAGE` code to use. Neither is `en` by the way. It seems like `bash` only uses English if no other language is set.

```
[bf@bf-laptop ~]$ LANGUAGE=en:it gerp
bash: gerp: comando non trovato...
Un comando simile è: 'grep'

[bf@bf-laptop ~]$ LANGUAGE=foo:bar:fr gerp
bash: gerp: commande inconnue...
Commande similaire : 'grep'
```

The [`LANGUAGE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/The-LANGUAGE-variable.html#The-LANGUAGE-variable) variable is used in the `gettext` library. The documentation there states:

> By default, an English message is shown in place of a nonexistent translation.

Comment: [`LANGUAGE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/The-LANGUAGE-variable.html#The-LANGUAGE-variable) is used by the `gettext` library, not `bash` directly.

Comment: @chepner thanks for the link. I have updated my answer.

Comment: KDE [Regional settings][Translations][Preferred languages] seems to set the LANGUAGE variable used by bash, so if I chose american english, french and italian (in that order), I would expect bash to display messages in english. Is that a bug in gettext ? I don't see how that would be by design.